# How to animate imported object

Tags: javascript, aframe

I followed the documentation of AFRAME of how to import objects.
What I have so far is:

```html
<a-scene embedded avatar-replayer="spectatorMode: true">
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="characterPreviewObj" src="оbj.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="characterPreviewMtl" src="obj.mtl"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity look-controls depth="0" scale=".001 .001 .001" obj-model="obj: #characterPreviewObj; mtl: #characterPreviewMtl">
        <a-camera position="0 0 0"></a-camera>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

The objects are .mtl and .obj. What I want to do is animate the imported object.
These objects have to move, shoot, make faces and a lot of other stuff.
How do I do that? Is there any specific methodology of doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Tsvetan Dimitrov

Answer (score 0):

Big picture - there are two different ways you can approach animation in this context:

**programmatic**, i.e changing certain parameters over time via code

**prebaked**, i.e working on intricate animations in a modeling/animation sofwtare like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) (free) or [Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview) (not free) and importing them to whatever environment you're working in.

The two approaches have very different use cases. 
Generally speaking the former is useful for trivial changes in position, rotation, scale, color and other easily accessible parameters, as well as procedural animation (flocking, fractals, a million other things) - but for intricate, specific animations like humanoid actions, facial expressions or movements with lots of small independent parts, you're going to want to create that animation in a dedicated software.

The scope of that process is beyond this answer but you can find plenty of useful information out there (useful google keywords: rigging, keyframes, shape keys, armatures... too many to mention here.)

As a final note: plenty of exchange file formats let you include animations in your exports from said software, but .obj isn't one of them:). Take a look at FBX, DAE and particularly glTF, which in many ways is future of 3D exchange formats.

Comment: A note I'd add to this: DAE is a popular format, but it's quite tricky to get DAE animation working in A-Frame. I'd recommend glTF, three.js JSON, and FBX (in that order).

Comment: This is a good tutorial on [prebaked animation](http://unboring.net/workflows/animation.html).